# Prepends css code before each css files using webpack loaders

Tags: css, webpack, postcss, postcss-loader

I utilize PostCSS in my project, and for each CSS file, I find myself needing to import a file containing custom defaults such as variables, resets, etc. I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this by configuring Webpack, possibly through the `postcss-loader` or other loaders.

I'm aware that `sass-loader` has the `additionalData` option, which allows you to include additional code in your SASS/SCSS files, but I couldn't find a similar feature for PostCSS.